# java.lang.Error in Cucumber StepDefinition (JAVA)

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

New to Java but fairly knowledgeable about Cucumber.

Here is what my feature steps look like:
@api_test
Feature: Title of your feature
  I want to use this template for my feature file

Scenario: Show Blog Post

Given I access the resource url "/comments?id=2"

When I retrieve the results

Then The status code should be 200

And It should have the field "id" containing the value "2"

And It should have the field "email" containing the value "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com"

---

When running feature test, i get following error:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
wc cannot be resolved
httpStatus cannot be resolved or is not a field
HttpStatusCode cannot be resolved to a variable
WebException cannot be resolved to a type
httpStatus cannot be resolved or is not a field
HttpWebResponse cannot be resolved to a type
HttpWebResponse cannot be resolved to a type
httpStatus cannot be resolved or is not a field
HttpStatusCode cannot be resolved to a variable
Assert cannot be resolved
response cannot be resolved or is not a field
JObject cannot be resolved to a type
JToken cannot be resolved
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```html
package stepDefinition;

import java.io.*;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When; 

import org.json.*;
import org.junit.Assert.*;
 
public class RestTestSteps {

   private String url;
   private String content;
   private WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   JObject response;
   HttpStatusCode httpStatus;

 

 @Given("^I access the resource url \"([^\"]*)\"$")
 public void i_access_the_resource_url(String resourceUrl) throws Throwable {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  this.url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" + resourceUrl;
 }

 @When("^I retrieve the results$")
 public void i_retrieve_the_results() throws Throwable {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  try
     {
       this.content = wc.DownloadString(url);
       this.httpStatus = HttpStatusCode.OK;
     }
     catch (WebException we)
     {
       this.httpStatus = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
     }
     if (this.httpStatus.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
     {
     Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(this.content);
     this.response = (JObject)JToken.Parse(this.content);
     }
     
 }

 @Then("^The status code should be (\\d+)$")
 public void the_status_code_should_be(int statusCode) throws Throwable {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  
  Assert.AreEqual(statusCode, (int)this.httpStatus);
  
 }

 @Then("^It should have the field \"([^\"]*)\" containing the value \"([^\"]*)\"$")
 public void it_should_have_the_field_containing_the_value(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  
      if (response != null)
      {
        JValue val = (JValue)this.response.GetValue(field);
        string valStr = val.Value().Trim();
        Assert.IsNotNull(valStr);
        Assert.AreEqual(valStr, value.Trim());
      }
  
 }

}
```

Not sure what im doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are missing imports. I see imports for the cucumber stuff, but I think you need to import the other classes you are using. If you are in an IDE like eclipse, it should help you add the necessary imports.

Additionally, you didn't import the asserts correctly. Those need to be imported as static.

`import static org.junit.Assert.*;`